# Change service name of Spring Cloud Dataflow Stream parts

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-skipper

When I deploy a new stream in Spring Cloud Dataflow I want to influence the service name, so that I can reach e.g. the source always under the same name. I already found this [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54468496/rational-behind-appending-versions-as-service-deployment-name-on-k8s-with-spring) but it doesn't mention how to turn this off. Looking at the deployed instances [I can see the property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nUmO.png).

I have checked all of the possible properties within Spring Cloud Dataflow, the Kubernetes deployer and Skipper but I cannot find a way to change the service name. When I was still running SCDF 1.7 I didn't have this problem. After upgrading to Skipper 2.1.2 and SCDF 2.2.1 I cannot get rid of it.