# How to apply a Static IP for Spring SCDF Stream that has a LoadBalancer (in Kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am deploying a stream with Spring SCDF. This stream also has a LoadBalancer. I activated that with the

```
spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.createLoadBalancer true
```

stream **Deployer** property.
So this LoadBalancer does work now and gives me an external IP that I can access. However this IP is changing each time I am redeploying the stream.

I am using GCP and there am able to provide a static IP. In Kubernetes I can give an ingress a static IP like so:

```
annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "web-static-ip"
```

I wonder how I can do the same for a deployed stream with Spring SCDF now?

Comment: Why you don't use ingress in front of the deployment? That way LB will be always there even when you redeploy the stream.

Comment: @Crou you mean deploying an ingress before we deploy the streams?
That is an idea but the problem is that Spring SCDF is deploying it's deployment resources with a suffix'ed name like `my-source-dev-43`. We were not able to find a way to get rid of that naming (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734738/change-service-name-of-spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-parts). Because of that we can't connect the Ingress to a service since the name is changing with every redeployed stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a production deployment setting, you'd want to have an explicit load-balancer (LB) attached to the desired application, so its service can be invoked by other services because there will be a static URL/IP to interact with it. Even if the app is rolling-upgraded or redeployed, you will get a predictable URL/IP.

Here's an example of the LB deployment:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: FOO-lb
  namespace: kafkazone
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: http
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    FOOZ: BAR-APP
  type: LoadBalancer
```

This deployment would produce a URL/IP. Let's say, for example, the IP address of `FOO-lb` is: `10.20.30.40`.

And, when you deploy the stream, you can attach a label selector to the desired application [e.g.: `deployer.<yourapp>.kubernetes.deploymentLabels=FOOZ: BAR-APP`], so all the incoming traffic to `10.20.30.40` will automatically be received by the source. You will be, of course, relying on the specific IP to post data or interact with it, and it will not change.

Comment: interesting - will try that